# Errors when trying to make a queue in C

Tags: c, struct, null, nodes

I'm writing a short program to create queues with nodes that have time stamps on them and will eventually split into threads. I've gotten stuck just on the writing a queue part and trying to print out the values. There are 3 errors the complier is giving me at various lines.

1. "error: invalid operands to binary == (have ‘node’ and ‘void *’)" on lines 16 and 29
2. "error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘node’ from type ‘struct node *’" on lines 35, 38 and 57.
3. "error: invalid initializer" on line 45.

I don't understand why I'm getting these errors and I don't know how to fix them. Here is the code:

```
  1 #include<stdio.h>
  2 #include<time.h>
  3 #include<pthread.h>
  4
  5 typedef struct node{
  6     int fd;
  7     time_t seconds;
  8     struct node *next;
  9 }node;
 10
 11 void dequeue(node);
 12 void enqueue(node, int);
 13
 14 void dequeue(node head){
 15
 16     if(head ==  NULL)
 17         return;
 18
 19     head.next = head.next->next;
 20     return;
 21 }
 22
 23 void enqueue(node head, int fd){
 24
 25     node curr;
 26     curr.fd = fd;
 27     curr.seconds = 0;
 28
 29     if(head == NULL){
 30         head = curr;
 31         return;
 32     }
 33
 34     while(head.next != NULL){
 35         head =  head.next;
 36     }
 37
 38     head.next = curr;
 39     return;
 40 }
 41
 42 int main(){
 43     node head = NULL;
 44     int i;
 45     printf("head ");
 46
 47     for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
 48         enqueue(head, i);
 49     }
 50
 51     printf("head");
 52     node tmp;
 53
 54     for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
 55         printf("-> node %d with value %d", i, tmp.fd);
 56         tmp = tmp.next;
 57     }
 58
 59     return 0;
 60 }
```

Comment: `void dequeue(struct node * head)` ... And anywhere else where you used `node` instead of `struct node *`, apart from when you want `sizeof` or defining the type itself.

Comment: Don't add line numbers to your code. Post it as-is (properly formated). What is your **specific problem? What did your C book not answer? One problem you have is likely using scopies of the objects instead of pointers. C ist strictly pass-by-value, how are your functions supposed to change e.g. `head` in the caller? I'd strongly recommend to (re-)read the chapter about pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You had a pile of bugs and errors in your code. I try to fix your code while trying to stick to the problem you're solving.

Always include the stdlib.h since it suppresses some pointer    arithmetic warnings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
```

Typedefing of a struct is a bad practice and also accessing a typedefed struct using the struct keyword is wrong.

```
struct node
{
   int fd;
   time_t seconds;
   struct node *next;
};
```

While defining the function signature, put the variable names alongside with their type to have a self descriptive function prototype.

```
struct node * dequeue(struct node *head);
struct node * enqueue(struct node *head, int fd);
```

The original `dequeue` function did not `free` the allocated space. Also, you need to return a pointer of `struct node` in order to update the `head` pointer.

```
struct node * dequeue(struct node *head)
{
   if(head !=  NULL)
   {    
      struct node *tmp = head;
      tmp = head->next;
      free(head);
      head = tmp;
      return(head);
   }
}
```

Both `if` and `while` conditions in the original `enqueue` function was wrong. Also, the putting a `return` inside a `void` function is incorrect.

```
struct node * enqueue(struct node *head, int fd)
{
   struct node *curr = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   curr->fd = fd;
   curr->seconds = 0;
   curr->next = NULL;

   if(head == NULL)
      head = curr;
   else
   {
      while(head->next != NULL)
         head =  head->next;
      head->next = curr;
      head = head->next;
   }
   return(head);
}
```

Your main function did not have proper arguments and had some problems. This is a more verbos version of it.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   struct node *head = NULL;
   struct node *tmp = head;

   // Enqueue 5 nodes   
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
      head = enqueue(head, i);
      printf("node %d with value %d enqueued\n", i, head->fd);
      if(i == 0)
          tmp = head;
   }
   printf("\n");

   //Traverse the queue
   head = tmp; 
   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
      printf("node %d with value %d traversed\n", i, head->fd);
      head = head->next;
   }
   printf("\n");

   // Dequeue 5 nodes   
   head = tmp; 
   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
      printf("node %d with value %d dequeued\n", i, head->fd);
      head = dequeue(head); 
      tmp = head;
   }
   return (0);
 }
```

Final remark: Life would be easier, if you learn how to work with pointers in C!